# How to proxy different WARs in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I'm developing a web application, which consists of two *independent* parts - the *authentication* and the *real application* part. Both parts are `WAR`s which are deployed at (currently) one Tomcat 7 instance.

So, I have the following two `WAR`s in my `webapps` folder:

```
webapps
|
+- BloggofantAuthentication
|
+- Bloggofant
```

until now they are available at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/BloggofanAuthentication` and `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Bloggofant`. Is it possible **proxy** the `WAR`s at Tomcat directly (so that I don't have to use `Apache httpd` and its `mod_proxy` module)? So that in the end, the `WAR`s at the server are reachable as follows:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/BloggofantAuthentication` -->
  `http://127.0.0.1/bloggo/`
- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Bloggofant` -->
  `http://127.0.0.1/bloggo/fant/`

Any suggestions on this topic are highly appreciated ;)

#### EDIT

Here are the `context.xml` files of the two unpacked webapp WAR folders:

**webapps/BloggofantAuthentication/META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="">
    <!-- Comment this to enable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

**webapps/Bloggofant/META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/bloggofant">
    <!-- Comment this to enable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

If I now want to access my apps via `http://127.0.0.1:8080` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/bloggofant` I get a **404 - Page Not Found** error ...

Comment: Why is the authentication not part of the webapp itself? Why don't you use contained-managed auth?

Comment: @Michael-O the authentication part is meant to be put on it's own Tomcat instance and serving a bunch of applications behind it - think of it as something like a "proxy" on it's own. I don't use contained-managed auth 'cause I have to use a backend API for this purpose and am not flexible about this issue...

Comment: OK and what's so special about you auth?

Comment: @Michael-O as much as I would like to discuss the needings and special requirements about my authentication, I'd like to know how I can "proxy" the two WAR archives at first - so please don't feel offended but I won't discuss this further as I want to move on with this topic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the path at which Tomcat serves a web application using a [context.xml file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html). You can put this in the WAR's META-INF directory, with the content:

```
<Context path="/bloggo/fant" />
```

And it will serve it there instead of at the default `/Bloggofant` path.

Note the [warning about automatic deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming) in the documentation:

> When autoDeploy or deployOnStartup operations are performed by a Host, the name and context path of the web application are derived from the name(s) of the file(s) that define(s) the web application. Consequently, the context path may not be defined in a META-INF/context.xml embedded in the application

Elsewhere, the documentation tells us that [these both default to true](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Common_Attributes). Thus, you will need to set them to false for these settings to be respected.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! I added the `<Context path="/bloggo"/>` line into the `context.xml` file under `webapps/BloggofantAuthentication/META-INF` and `<Context path="/bloggo/fant"/>` line into `context.xml` under `webapps/Bloggofant/META-INF` and restarted Tomcat 7. If I now want to access the pages all I see is a blank page (no error, though)...

Comment: do you have any further hints or suggestions? Please see also my edit on the first post with the contents of both `context.xml` files...

Comment: Hmm. You also need to disable automatic deployment - see my edit.

Comment: ahh, I see - thanks a lot I totally missed this point. It works now! Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry, i missed it too!